# Trouble with IPC::Open3

Tags: perl, ipc

I am writing a simple script using IPC::Open3.  The script produces no output to either stdout or stderr, while I would expect output to both.

The complete source code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use IPC::Open3;

pipe my $input, my $output or die $!;
my $pid =  open3(\*STDIN, $output, \*STDERR, 'dd', 'if=/usr/include/unistd.h') or die $!;

while(<$input>) {
    print $_."\n";
}
waitpid $pid, 0;
```

I am fairly certain that I am using IPC::Open3 incorrectly.  However, I am still confused as to what I *should* be doing.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `pipe`?

Comment: Don't know, it probably should be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `pipe`. Without knowing why it's there I can't say more. This works fine.

```
my $reader;
my $pid =  open3(\*STDIN, $reader, \*STDERR, 'dd', 'if=/usr/include/unistd.h') or die $!;

while(<$reader>) {
    print $_."\n";
}
waitpid $pid, 0;
```

I realize it's *probably* just an example, but in case it's not... this is complete overkill for what you're doing. You can accomplish that with backticks.

```
print `dd if=/usr/include/unistd.h`
```

---

IPC::Open3 is a bit overcomplicated. There are better modules such as [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) and [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Run3;

run3(['perl', '-e', 'warn "Warning!"; print "Normal\n";'],
     \*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR
);
```

Comment: I still don't get the stderr output though, even when I use a shell command that redirects some stuff to stderr.

Comment: @Demi open3() is difficult to work with. I've expanded the answer with better modules to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your program suffers from the following problems:

- `\*STDIN` (open `STDIN` as a pipe tied to the child's `STDIN`) should be `<&STDIN` (use the parent's `STDIN` as the child's `STDIN`).
- `\*STDERR` (open `STDERR` as a pipe tied to the child's `STDERR`) should be `>&STDERR` (use the parent's `STDERR` as the child's `STDERR`).
- The value you place in `$output` is being ignored and overwritten. Fortunately, it's being overwritten with a correct value!
- You use `print $_."\n";`, but `$_` is already newline-terminated. Either `chomp` first, or don't add a newline.
- `open3` isn't a system call, so it doesn't set `$!`.
- `open3` doesn't return false on error; it throws an exception.

So we get something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use IPC::Open3;

my $pid = open3('<&STDIN', my $output, '>&STDERR',
    'dd', 'if=/usr/include/unistd.h');

while (<$output>) {
    chomp;
    say "<$_>";
}

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Comment: That closes STDIN, which I don't want, but I can solve that with a couple of `open` calls to duplicate file descriptors.  Thanks!

Comment: I think `open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<&', \*STDIN) or die $!;` and `'<&CHILD_STDIN'` will do, though you may encounter issue without duping an input handle.