# More trouble with IPC::Open3

Tags: perl, ipc

I asked about IPC::Open3 in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948414/trouble-with-ipcopen3).  However, I still am having problems.

This code hangs, rather than waiting until EOF is seen on stdin.  It also fails to write anything to stderr.

This is not a duplicate because that question asks about capturing output, while this question asks about input.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use v5.10;

use IPC::Open3;

use Symbol 'gensym';

my $output;
# pipe my $input, $output or die $!;
my $pid =  open3(\*STDIN, $output, \*STDERR, 'sh',
   '-c', 'echo 1 >&2; cat /usr/include/unistd.h -') or die $!;


while (<$output>) {
    say $output;
}
waitpid $pid, 0;
```

Comment: This is beginning to sound like an [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Can you explain what it is that you are ultimately trying to do?  It seems like part of what you want to do is execute a shell command and capture it's STDERR and STDOUT and to display STDOUT to be seen by the user.  Are you also wanting to take STDIN from the script to send that into the shell command too?

Comment: If you want to just capture the STDERR and STDOUT from a shell command, you can check out the capture function from [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny).  It will let you capture the STDERR, STDOUT and exit code.  If you also want to display STDOUT while also capture the STDERR and STDOUT, then maybe one of the tee function from Capture::Tiny would work for you.

Comment: @ikegami I have edited this question to explain why this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: The answer is identical. Both programs suffer from exactly the same problems

Answer (score 1):

Your program suffers from the following problems:

- `\*STDIN` (open `STDIN` as a pipe tied to the child's `STDIN`) should be `<&STDIN` (use the parent's `STDIN` as the child's `STDIN`).
- `\*STDERR` (open `STDERR` as a pipe tied to the child's `STDERR`) should be `>&STDERR` (use the parent's `STDERR` as the child's `STDERR`).
- `say $output;` should be `say $_;` or just `say;`.
- You use `say`, but the value you are printing is already newline-terminated. Either use `chomp` first, or switching to using `print`.
- `open3` isn't a system call, so it doesn't set `$!`.
- `open3` doesn't return false on error; it throws an exception.

Note that if you pass a single scalar as the command, it will be passed to `sh -c`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

my $pid = open3('<&STDIN', my $output, '>&STDERR',
  'echo 1 >&2; cat /usr/include/unistd.h -');

while (<$output>) {
    chomp;
    say "<$_>";
}

waitpid($pid, 0);
```